# Change a keyboard layout for already typed text

Tags: windows, keyboard-layout, text-editing

I have 2 keyboard layouts (Russian and English) on my Windows laptop. It often happens that I start printing some symbols using the wrong layout.

And typically what I do is

1. delete already entered text
2. change the keyboard layout
3. reprint the text with the right layout.

Is it possible to automate this process? For example, select some text, hit some hotkeys so it will automatically modify symbols according to the next keyboard layout. Maybe there is a specific tool for it?

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe there is a native way to do this within Windows. However, there does appear to be a piece of software called *Ochepyatka* which allows you to do this.

From their website:

> Using Ochepyatka you can convert text between different keyboard layouts within a second! Just select an incorrect text fragment and press appropriate keyboard shortcut - the program will make some magic and fix your text immediately!

Answer (score 0):

There is a special hotkey for this. I accidentally pressed some keys in the lower-left corner of the keyboard, and it successfully changed the written text layout (for example: from руддщ to hello). But I do not exactly know which keys. The combination of Ctrl, Shift, Alt, Windows key, or even CAPS LOCK I do not really know.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1154833)